# python mysql, connect to latest DB of many?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am currently running into what feels like a simple solution but perhaps I could get some help.

I am currently writing a python script that connects to a database server to retrieve the latest information, but I am running into one key issue.

There is no one 'database'. The tool that creates the data I need, creates a new 'database' every time it generates information. So when I connect to the server, there's literally 30+ databases, and it constantly creates new ones every week when the program runs its data collections.

So for example, I have a database called collection_2016_9_15, collection_2016_9_9, etc etc. This becomes a problem because when I want to run a query I need to tell python which DB to connect to, and this is supposed to be automated.

So right now, since it runs weekly, I know I can basically run the script the day the data is collected, and just say connect to database collection_Y%_M%_D%, but that will only work if I run it on the day the program runs, so if anything causes a delay or issues, it will break the automation.

So is there any way to tell python to connect to the 'most recent database' without trying to give it a specific name?

Comment: You can probably get names of already created databases and then compare them and get the most recent, is that ok?

Comment: I was hoping for something a little more 'agnostic' so that I dont have to make names at all. Otherwise yeah, that is my currently plan.

Comment: You can also store name of the last database in some memory or smth like that, so that you could easily access that value and database without proceeding list of names.